# ThunderBird blocks images from templates located in subdir (nested template dir)

Tags: thunderbird

In ThunderBird I create some templates for email.
When I take a look on this template it looks fine.
When I try to use them then I see a warning that my images was blocked.

How to fix this issue and start to using templates without any problem even if template contain images.

btw. I am not able to unlock each image individually because trying to unlock the first one causes the unlock option to no longer display the list and no items can be displayed.

[image]

The email templates contains PNG encoded as BASE64 so there is no refrerence to any URL, so from my understanding they are not external, but local image.

[image]

I have turned on `external content in messages`.
Also checked with turned off.

[image]

**Step by step reproducing procedure:**

1. create email with image
2. save as temlate
3. go to template dir
4. create sub dir in template dir ! "sub dir" with space in the name
5. move saved template to the subdir
6. try to create email using template located in the subdir

In my case the "sub dir" is `NOWY ROK`
[image]

and in properties it looks like: `Templates/NOWY%20ROK`
[image]

Comment: When you compse your message, for each image make sure that in the image options dialogue the  "Attach this image to the message" box is checked, otherwise the image will be inserted as an external link.

Comment: When you say "compose your message" you mean compose in ThunderBrid or here in website ?

Comment: I am not including an image as an attachment. I just paste image (from system clipboard) contextually into the email content, and after that saving templates.

Comment: Pasting images can cause issues (not only in tb). Drag-and-drop -> inline or add through the menu

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue, it's a normal behavior. `Thunderbird` blocks external content like images by default for privacy purposes.

> Remote content are parts of a message (such as images, stylesheets, or
> videos) which are not included in the message itself, but are
> downloaded from the Internet when you view the message.
>
> Remote content is a privacy concern because it allows the message
> sender to know:
>
> 1. each time you view the message
> 2. rough details about what application and what platform you are using
> 3. your current geographic location (a rough approximation by IP address)
> 4. that your email address is actually used ("active")

[Reference](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remote-content-in-messages)

---

To enable external content by default, you need to go in `Preferences` > `Privacy & Security` > Check `Allow remote content in messages`.

You can also create exceptions for some email addresses or domains to not load their content.

---

By default in `Thunderbird`, if you copy and paste an image inside a template / email, it will create an external link.

To prevent this, you need to `attach` image in your template / email. **It does not mean** "put the image in attachment", it means include the image inside the email without adding external links (encode image in `base64`). Here is where you can attach images (`Insert` > `Image`) :

[image]

By doing this, you won't have any link or `imap://xxxx` in the source code of the email and you won't have any blocking problems.

Comment: But from my point they are not external, they are on my own email account.
I mean they are my own email saved as template in my IMAP account.

Comment: Are they included directly in the body of the email ? Without looking for them on the internet with a link ? You should check the original code of the email to check. - If a download is required, they are tagged as external.

Comment: The email templates contains PNG encoded as BASE64 so there is no refrerence to any URL, so from my understanding they are not external, but local image.

Comment: On your first image, I see several links like `imap://something/some_other_things`, that is considered as external links. - Maybe there are others images ?

Comment: `imap://` URL's are referencing to IMAP (email account) not to any normal external URL.

Comment: `imap://` URL's are just EMAIL account and should not be considered as an external URL. It is, after all, an email account in itself.

Comment: Yes I understand, what is happening if you allow external content temporary ? Is it still blocked ? - At least we will be sure whether Thunderbird considers it external (or not).

Comment: On which email address you sent the template ? The same one ? Or another ? - I mean the email of your first image. - Maybe check the source code of a sent email, not the template itself.

Comment: updated Opening Post. I do not sent template. Template is saved in template dir on IMAP server.

Comment: So when you say `When I try to use them then I see a warning that my images was blocked.`. What do you mean exactly ? - Have you tried to restart Thunderbird when you enabled the `Allow remote content in messages` option ?

Comment: `Maybe check the source code of a sent email, not the template itself` I just create template with images. Save template to IMAP template directory. Preview of the template looks good. And now when I trying to create new email using this templeate I get new email created but with out the images, because images are blocked. So I do not send the emial to any one because email should conatain images, but the problem is that there is no one image.

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/insert-inline-image-thunderbird-1173116 according to @1NN comment.

Comment: `Have you tried to restart Thunderbird when you enabled the Allow remote content in messages option ?` checked again no postive results, still the same issue.

Comment: You need to attach images in the email itself.

Comment: `lifewire.com/insert-inline-image-thunderbird-1173116 according to @1NN comment` I am not including an image as an attachment. I just paste contextually into the email content.

Comment: I think I just found where the issue is.
Step by step:
1. create email with image 2. save as temlate 3. go to template dir 4. create sub dir in template dir 5. move saved template to the subdir 6. try to create email using template located in the subdir

Comment: updated OP. Any body can confirm this issue ?

Comment: I updated my answer for more information. Tell me if it helps you.

Comment: `By doing this, you won't have any link or imap://xxxx in the source code of the email and you won't have any blocking problems` this didn't solve the problem. By attaching a file this way, after saving the template, the content of this template still contains PNG encoded as BASE64, and an attempt to create a new email based on the template created in this way still blocks its content. .... doing some more test.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the "sub dir" is `NOWY ROK`

[image]

and in properties it looks like: `Templates/NOWY%20ROK`

[image]

And fix/solution was to change sub dir name from `NOWY ROK` to `NOWY_ROK`

[image]

But after considering the problem, I believe that this is a ThunderBird bug.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1872698